# Get all contacts from exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get all users from Exchange server, I don't want to get user's contacts. In fact, I want to get all AD users as Active Directory which we can't connect to.

```
     mExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId
        {
            Id = "jack@aa.com",
            IdType = ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress
        };
        var contacts = _mExchangeService.FindItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts),new ItemView(1000));
```

I can above code to get user's contact, but that's not I want, I want use a service account to get all Exchange web service users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort of use EWS for retrieving your directory users using [`ExhangeService.ResolveName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename(v=exchg.80).aspx).  The problem is that EWS will return no more than 100 users and there is no way to change it or to do any paging.  So if you are in a larger company you can't really do it using EWS.

The code:

```
var nameResolutionCollection = service.ResolveName("SMTP:",
    ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);
foreach (var c in nameResolutionCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Mailbox.Address);
}
Console.WriteLine(nameResolutionCollection.Count()); // Maximum 100 users.
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, but just can get 100 records, It's strange why just provide 100 records

Comment: Thank you for this Jakob! Sadly, 100 where not enough for our company's ActiveDirectory. Is there another option you know of, or do I have to go through [ActiveDirectory directly](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory)?

Comment: @Tholle: I think Active Directory is the way to go.